# Cannot get material-ui datepicker to work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

For some reason, I cannot get the **material-ui** datepicker to work. Every time the datepicker is rendered in React, the following error is thrown:

> RangeError: Format string contains an unescaped latin alphabet character `n`

I have created a stackblitz with just the datepicker (https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-6ma6xd?embed=1&file=index.js) and even there the error shows up. What am I doing wrong? I think I followed all the instructions from the installation guide.

Link to the material-ui/pickers: https://material-ui-pickers.dev/

Comment: In the meantime, I also see they have updated their documentation.

Comment: I had the same problem. After experiencing this, I can already tell that the road that lies ahead is long using this framework.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

I had the same problem, found this in the github issues:

https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui-pickers/issues/1440
so i installed "@date-io/date-fns": "^1.3.13" and got it working

Comment: someone just wrote a different text from mine which changed, not the information but definitly the tone. So I'm changing it back. If you don't like the answer's wording, please maybe write a different answer for others to upvote

Comment: It is important to bear in mind that it is required to close and restart the server after downgrading the module, especially if you are using Windows.

Comment: Downgrading to @date-io/date-fns@1.x worked for me

Comment: Oh man, @LuisFebro you cannot imagine how much time you saved me... Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 51):

Downgrade your package to `@date-io@^1.3.13`

`npm i @date-io/date-fns@1.3.13`

Comment: The [installation instructions](https://material-ui-pickers.dev/getting-started/installation#peer-library) now explain exactly what to install.

Comment: @DanDascalescu Your link is dead

Answer (score 12):

Just use momentJS:
npm i @date-io/moment@1.x moment

```
import MomentUtils from '@date-io/moment';

function App() {
  return (
    <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={MomentUtils}>
```

Comment: "Just" use moment? You might want to check [this](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/3376).

Comment: Replacing date-fns with moment has fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 11):

I tried the answers above it didn't work but they gave me clue to the solution, you'll have to make a full downgrade if the previous answers don't work for you

```
npm install @material-ui/pickers@3.2.8
npm install @date-io/date-fns@1.3.13
npm install date-fns@2.8.1
```

Answer (score 4):

Looks like the material-ui-pickers example is using the following dependency versions (which are different from yours):

```
"@date-io/date-fns": "1.0.1",
"material-ui-pickers": "2.1.1",
```

In your example, you are using a newer version of @date-io with a deprecated version of material-ui-pickers:

```
"@date-io/date-fns": "2.0.1",
"@material-ui/pickers": "3.2.8",
```

You can (1) set your versions to match the example or (2) use the latest material-ui-pickers version and perform the date formatting using a custom function instead of DateFnsUtils.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think I am using the latest packages. The ones you send as a suggestion seem to be the ones who are deprecated, which I would rather not use in production. 
All the packages I used are from running the commands in the installation guide (https://material-ui-pickers.dev/getting-started/installation)

Answer (score 4):

you need to install

> npm i @date-io/date-fns@1.x date-fns

from offical site .
https://material-ui-pickers.dev/getting-started/installation
and follow their instructions.

Comment: This is why posting links is frowned upon.  Your link is dead.

Answer (score 3):

For me the only thing that was creating this issue was the order of import statement.Make sure you:

`import 'date-fns'`; before importing `import DateFnsUtils from '@date-io/date-fns'`;

i.e

```
import 'date-fns'
import DateFnsUtils from '@date-io/date-fns';
```

Answer (score 2):

it's due to material ui pickers v3 conflict with @date-io, can visit official site

[Important: For material-ui-pickers v3 use v1.x version of @date-io adapters.](https://material-ui-pickers.dev/getting-started/installation)

Answer (score 2):

that's because you installed @date-io@2.* you might see the error

Uncaught RangeError: Format string contains an unescaped latin alphabet character `n`

you have to downgrade to @date-io@^1.3.13.

Answer (score 1):

No need to downgrade **@date.io/date-fns**, Just format Date properly as said in https://github.com/date-fns/date-fns/blob/master/docs/unicodeTokens.md

```
      <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
          <Grid item>
            <KeyboardDatePicker
              margin="normal"
              id="date-picker-dialog"
              label="Date picker dialog"
              views={['year', 'month', 'date']}
              value={selectedDate}
              format="dd/MM/yyyy"
              onChange={handleDateChange}
              KeyboardButtonProps={{
                'aria-label': 'change date',
              }}
            />
          </Grid>
        </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
```

Answer (score 1):

### React

If you did like me and made a wrapper for this, you should check your other props.
I got this error by mistakenly sending in `Date.now()` as the label prop, so it could have nothing to do with your `format` or `@date.io/date-fns`

Answer (score 0):

As suggested [here](https://material-ui-pickers.dev/getting-started/installation), use v1.x version of @date-io adapters with material-ui-pickers v3.

Answer (score 0):

This happens as well if you pass `undefined` as format string. Make sure you don't accidentally pass `undefined` as format string.